# Вопросики вместо кириллицы при печати данных от pymysql на Питоне 3

Tags: база-данных, python-3.x, кодировка, кириллица

Считываю текст с базы данных и получаю вместо русских символов вопросы:

```
? ????? ????? ?????, ? ??? ???? ???
```

Код:

```
db = pymysql.connect(************)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT username, message FROM messages WHERE anon = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " + count
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    messages = []
    for item in result:
        messages.append(item[0] + ": " + item[1])

    messages = " | ".join(messages).replace("\r\n", "")
    print(messages)
    utils.mess(s, "/w " + username + " " + messages)
    db.close()
```

Пароль и логин бд заменил звездочками

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Лишний код уберите. Если print(result) уже одни вопросики печатает, то остальной код уже не нужен.

Comment: Покажите print(ascii(result))

Comment: Я уже исправил, добавил charset='utf8' в подключении к бд

Answer (score 4):

В подключении к БД добавил в конце `charset='utf8'`. Это решило проблему.